# Loading an image file and saving to database

Tags: c++, blob, c++builder

This is the last bit of the problem I have saving image to database and retrieving it. What I am trying to do now is to make it generic (before it was ico files and it worked) by using `TWICImage`. I am able to save and load it, but I get an exception while saving to the database.

> Could not convert variant of type (Array Byte) into type (Integer)

If I click ok, everything is as usual. It is saved and loads and displays just fine. It must me something that I did wrong, but can't figure it out.

Here is the loading from file code snippet:

```
if (dlgOpenPictureFile->Execute())
{
  TWICImage *Image = new TWICImage();

  Image->LoadFromFile(dlgOpenPictureFile->FileName);

  imgLogo->Picture = NULL;
  imgLogo->Picture->Assign(Image);

  if (dscMain->DataSet->State == dsBrowse)
  {
    dscMain->Edit();
  }

  TStream *StreamLogo = NULL;

  try
  {
    StreamLogo = dscMain->DataSet->CreateBlobStream(dscMain->DataSet->FieldByName("Image"), bmWrite);
    imgLogo->Picture->Graphic->SaveToStream(StreamLogo);
  }
  __finally
  {
    //at the time of delete it writes to the underlying buffer
    delete StreamLogo;
    delete Image;
  }
}
```

`dscMain` is the datasource which we later post. The `Image` is of the type `varbinary` in the database.

Any insights to this problem is very much appreciated.

**Edit:**
After some testing, it looks like this is happening only for .png and .gif files.

IDE: Rad Studio Berlin

OS: Windows 10

Comment: "*If I click ok, everything is as usual. **It is saved and loads and displays just fine**.*" - then it sounds like the DB code is throwing an internal exception that it is handling internally, so your code never sees it. If that is the case, you would see the exception only when running your code inside of the debugger, and as such can safely ignore it if the DB code is actually working correctly at runtime. If you don't want to see the exception at debug-time, tell the debugger to ignore it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you for your comment. Gives little more insight. I get the error during run time as well. The above code did not give an exception when the `Image` was of the type `TIcon`. I just changed it to `TWICImage`, to handle generic images, which started this error. So I wanted to know if I am doing it right.

Comment: usual way of doing this is convert the image file into Base64 encoded string store as such and when retrieving restore back to binary ... this way avoids any hidden control codes that might disrupt the processing at any level (which seems like the cause of your problems) ... but it requires slightly more memory (2 bits per BYTE are wasted)